# A simpler way to switch axis in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I am doing an exercise from DataQuest and I have a database from a Star Wars survey.

Source can be found here:

https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/star-wars-survey

Columns ranking_1 to ranking_6 contains the rankings of the first 6 Star Wars movies. I want to show the rankings on a bar plot by gender.

```
ranking_gender_avg = star_wars.groupby(['Gender']) [star_wars.columns[9:15]].mean()
print(ranking_gender_avg)

ranking_gender_avg.plot.bar()
```

[image: x axis by gender]

I want to switch the x-axis to show rankings and the bars to show gender so I have this:

```
ranking_gender_avg = star_wars.groupby(['Gender'])[star_wars.columns[9:15]].mean()
print(ranking_gender_avg)

ranking_gender_avg.T.plot.bar() #All I did was use T for transpose.
```

[image: x axis by rankings]

**Question:** How would I create the second graph without using transpose? Is there a simpler way? I am new to python and it just happened that I stumbled upon the transpose method. I am interested to see if there is a way to group by rankings then split into genders.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the groupby argument like that:

```
ranking_gender_avg = star_wars.groupby(['Ranking', 'Gender']).mean()
```